# How to reassign an Application Pool (not Identity) for SharePoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, application-pool, administration

**Background**: Our server beyond the recommended limit for SP2013 ([Software Boundaries and Limits](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#WebserverAppServer])) on the number of Application Pools per server (10). I'm wondering if that is what is causing a noticeable lag, especially in Central Administration.  I already fixed a time-out issue by [extending the "Shutdown Time Limit"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112358/not-able-to-create-web-application-in-sp-2013/112364#112364) in IIS, but would like also to optimize the performance.

**Question**: I'd like several of the SP Web Applications grouped to share an AppPool, so I have 3 AppPools instead more than 10.  By order of preference (1) How do I do this in Central Administration, (2) in PowerShell, (3) or in IIS (most likely not the recommended practice)?  What is the best practice?

**Update** (6/29/17): I actually ended up deleted 5 unused Web Apps (7 left, including Central Admin).  That didn't really fix the lag issue on the WFE side, but this these two Powershell commands seem to:

```
    PS> Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService -PerformanceLevel PartlyReduced  
    PS> Restart-Service SPSearchHostController
```

*Credit*: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125174/reduce-noderunner-exe-impact

---

**I still have a lag with making changes in Central Admin.  Still seeking a solution for that.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you create a web application in sharepoint, you are invited to create a new application pool, via central admin.

Each time you create a service application in sharepoint (search, user profile, managed metadata), you are invited to create a new application pool, via central admin.

If you want to re assign the app pool, you can navigate to central admin > Manage service application > Select the service > Click properties in the ribbon > Change the applicaiton pool.

As for powershell code to create app pool or re assign services, i do not have them.

From IIS side you shall only create application pool in case you want to re assign existing services applicaitons to new app pool.

As for your central admninistration slowness, may you share your existing machine specs ? For a developer VM, I have run my VM fast with 4vcpu / 24 gb ram / 8 gb for sql (limit the sql instance to 8gb) / set the search to minimal performance (there are powershell for this)

Comment: If Central Admin had the same modify functionality as "Manage service applications" steps you gave me, I'd be set.  Instead, so far, I've settled on deleting and recreating our unused SPWebApps, and created an AppPool shared by several WebApps.  Googling showed that even the Powershell method had many steps and one site recommended not doing it on a production environment.

Comment: ..even doing that, didn't really fix the lag issue on the WFE side, but this these two Powershell commands did: 
1) Set-SPEnterpriseSearchService -PerformanceLevel PartlyReduced

2) Restart-Service SPSearchHostController

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125174/reduce-noderunner-exe-impact

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. There is such options in central admin (Sharepoint 2013 on premise), maybe you talk about an other product ?

Comment: Regarding setting the search to minimum is it not recommended for production use, but for development environment yes. Maybe your IOPS or RAM allocated is unsufficient ? You mind sharing your VM Specs (CPU / RAM) ?

Comment: Not the issue, though -- it's a VM: Intel Xeon CPU E5-4620 0 @2.20GHz with 24GB RAM

Comment: I was getting this error from SP Health Analyzer. I resolved it by creating/assigning separate Service Accounts. Seemed to help: "The server farm account should not be used for other services. 
[DOMAIN\FarmAccount], the account used for the SharePoint timer service and the central administration site, is highly privileged and should not be used for any other services on any machines in the server farm.  The following services were found to use this account: ... 
Browse to http://.../_admin/FarmCredentialManagement.aspx and change the account used for the services listed in the explanation."